# Find minimum of $y=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}-\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

> Find minimum of $y=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}-\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}$

#### My work so far:

1) $$y =\frac{2x+9}{\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}+\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}} $$

2) I used a derivative and found the answer ($y=\sqrt3$ at $x=0$). Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the function that way only complicates things.

First let's determine the domain:
\begin{cases}
-x^2+4x+12\ge0\\
-x^2+2x+3\ge0
\end{cases}
reduces to $-1\le x\le3$.

The derivative is
$$
y'=
\frac{-x+2}{\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}}-
\frac{-x+1}{\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}}
$$
(which is undefined at $-1$ and $3$) and we want to see where it vanishes, that is,
$$
(2-x)\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}=(1-x)\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}
$$
We need either $-1<x<1$ or $2<x<3$ so that both terms are either positive or negative. Now we can square safely:
$$
(2-x)^2(-x^2+2x+3)=(1-x)^2(-x^2+4x+12)
$$
becomes $12x^2-16x=0$, so the only critical point is $0$ (because $4/3$ doesn't satisfy the above limitations).

We also have
$$
f(-1)=\sqrt{7},\qquad
f(0)=\sqrt{3},\qquad
f(3)=\sqrt{15}
$$
Since maxima and minima are at critical points or at the extremes of the domain, we can conclude.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Domain gives $-1\leq x\leq3$.

If $x=0$ so $y=\sqrt3$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value of $y$.

Id est, we need to prove that 
$$\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}+\sqrt3\leq\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}$$ or after squaring of the both sides we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{3(-x^2+2x+3)}\leq x+3$$ or since $x+3>0$, we need to prove that
$$3(-x^2+2x+3)\leq(x+3)^2,$$
which is $x^2\geq0$.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\sqrt{-x^2+4x+12}-\sqrt{-x^2+2x+3}$$
$$\implies y=\sqrt{16-4-x^2+4x}-\sqrt{4-1-x^2+2x}$$
$$\implies y=\sqrt{16-(4+x^2-4x)}-\sqrt{4-(1+x^2-2x)}$$
$$\implies y=\sqrt{16-(2-x)^2}-\sqrt{4-(1-x)^2}$$

From the first radical, we have that $$-4 \le 2-x\le 4 \implies -2 \le x\le 6$$
And from the second radical, we have that $$-2 \le 1-x\le 2 \implies -1 \le x\le 3$$

Net domain will be $[-1,3]$.

Further $y(-1)=\sqrt7$ , $y(0)=\sqrt{12}-\sqrt3$ , $y(1)=\sqrt{15}-2$, $y(2)=4-\sqrt{3}$ and $y(3)=0$

See if this helps.

Comment: But how would you say that where is it minimum, with 100% surity, also $y(-1)$ isn't $0$.

Comment: @JaideepKhare I never said this is the total solution .. read the last line carefully : **See if this helps** ... it means , it is left to the OP to think and make use of my idea in whatever way he can think of ... and if, at all possible to get any help from it ..

Comment: OK! Sorry if that sounded rude.

Answer (score -2):

find the first derivative $dy/dx$ and set it equal to zero. Study the variation in case you are looking for a "local" minimum.

Comment: I used a derivative and found the answer

Comment: If you have give suggestions, comment.If you have to give solutions, then only answer.